# Request: GET petition using request node.js call response function twice

Tags: node.js, firebase, http, request, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase cloud function that attacks an API, gets some data and  after serialize it, it upload the data to my Firestore database. This is scheduled using Cron to be executed daily. My function works fine and everything is OK. But my http request is calling the success function twice.

I'm using [request](https://github.com/request/request) for manage the HTTP petition. My code looks like:

```
return request({
    uri: uri,
    method: "GET",
    qs: propertiesObject,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return serializeResponse(body, region, bracket, firebaseResponse)
    } else {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        return firebaseResponse.status(400).send("The petition to Battle.NET API has failed");
    }
});
```

The method `serializeResponse` just serialize the given data and upload it to Firestore, nothing else. `FirebaseResponse` is the original response from the http request to the cloud function that needs to be close sending a success or error code to avoid an infinite loop of execution.

However, the problem is that the `function` is being called twice, and I can't figure out why. Before I add a stupid boolean control or something ugly to the code, I'd prefer to seek help.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time a page is requested the browser defaults to favicon.ico, make a judgment

```
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;    
if(pathname != '/favicon.ico'){
}
```